# generate cv::Mat out of a text file

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I used this piece of code to write descriptors in a text file , but I dont know how to laod them back in a cv::Mat again, what is the function that does the opposite !!

[How to crete a SIFT's descriptors database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849592/how-to-crete-a-sifts-descriptors-database/23150409?noredirect=1#comment35399623_23150409)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849592/how-to-crete-a-sifts-descriptors-database/23150409?noredirect=1#comment35399623_23150409)

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: here is the link to the code i used !! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849592/how-to-crete-a-sifts-descriptors-database/23150409?noredirect=1#comment35399623_23150409)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XML/YAML file storages provided by the OpenCV class Filestorage.

The question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550021/converting-a-mat-file-from-matlab-into-cvmat-matrix-in-opencv).

Comment: and how would i concatenate all those yml files in one files, that i can use as a kmeans input !! ?